# What reinterpret_cast convention is this? is it better than static_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, coding-style, conventions, reinterpret-cast

I'm looking through some c++ wrapper code that provides a c api, and I'm finding lots of `reinterpret_cast` where a `static_cast` would suffice, e.g.:

```
struct cpp_object{ void foo(){ /* do something */ } };

/* begin: c api */
typedef void c_object;

void foo(c_object *o)
{
    // why this:
    reinterpret_cast<cpp_object *>(o)->foo();
    // instead of just:
    static_cast<cpp_object *>(o)->foo();
}
/* end: c api */
```

Generally I use `reinterpret_cast` in rare situations, mostly related to forced bit coersion of buffer contents to a type of know layout and size, known to lie inside buffer contents.

So I ask whether that practice makes sense or sticking to `static_cast` would be a better one.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `reinterpret_cast` is equivalent to a `static_cast` to `cv void*` and then another `static_cast` to the target pointer type. This is an addition to C++11 I believe and wasn't present in C++03, where you had to write the two `static_cast`s to get portable behaviour.

Comment: but the void pointer parameters being accepted doesn't have any cv qualification, so `const_cast` is never necessary and `static_cast` works.

Comment: @chico `static_cast` can add cv-qualifiers it just can't remove them. `cv void*` in my example is to indicate that it `static_cast`s to a `void*` where the `void` has the same cv-qualifications as the source pointer.

Comment: yes, I know that, probably you meant then a `const_cast` after the first `static_cast` but in any case... the parameters have no cv qualification, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @chico You've lost me. `reinterpret_cast<cpp_object*>(o)` is equivalent to `static_cast<cpp_object*>(static_cast<void*>(o))`. There is no `const_cast` involved in a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: ok, but, as I'm trying to say. `o` is already just `void *` isn't? there's no cv requalification in that cast. That's what I was trying to say, but, anyway, now I ask, that first cast seems unecessary, unless it's turned so because I'm dealing with pointers for typedefs to `void`?

Comment: @chico It will still convert the `void*` that is `o` into another `void*` and then do the final cast. This doesn't matter though because it has no runtime overhead. I actually didn't notice `c_object` was an alias for `void`, in which case I would prefer just using `static_cast` but this answer still applies.

Comment: ok, I'm no interested in the runtime aspect, my only concern now, with your reasoning, is whether this first cast you made is not mandatory or mandatory good practice, if it's not, then it can be removed, and a single `static_cast` already should do the job, no need for `reinterpret_cast` backed by that reasoning.

Comment: C++03 already allowed `static_cast` to convert from a `void*` to an object pointer type, see [expr.static.cast]/10.

Comment: ah, ok, you've already answered that in the previous comment...

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you have to use `reinterpret_cast` because  `c_object` is of type `void`,
so `o` is of `void *`. The compiler can not guess that `o` is. It has to be a run-time cast.

Comment: You're mistaken, it's just casting from `void *` to some other pointer, which is allowed.